# Can only get previous rotation

Tags: objective-c, ios, uideviceorientation

In my objects init method

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                                                    name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" 
                                                  object:nil];
```

did Rotate Method

```
- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSLog(@"rotate notification");

    //MA_MobileAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MA_MobileAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = appDelegate.tabBarController.interfaceOrientation;
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

For some reason the didRotate seems to be called before the actual rotation. Thus when I try to get the current/final rotation I get the last one. There is only 1 view controller that this doesn't seem to be the case. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to delay my code

```
[self performBlock:^(id sender) {

//rotation code

} afterDelay:0.1f];
```

The short delay is all that was needed to give UIApplication the time to update the statusbar orientation property :(

Comment: I'm going to test it and see if it works. I will either mark his or my answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

iOS tracks two separate orientations: the device orientation (`[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`) and the interface orientation (`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]`).  A change to the device orientation may trigger a change to the interface orientation.  You're receiving the device-orientation-change notification before the system has changed the interface orientation.

Try observing [`UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW40).  It's posted by `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a timing issue.  Rob is correct in asserting that Device orientation is different from Interface Orientation.  You can very obviously see this happen when you place your device flat on a table and shake the table.  Device orientation changes a ton, Interface orientation is likely to not switch.

Comment: Since the object in question is a UIViewController, it will receive interface rotation events anyway if it is added to the view controller hierarchy.  Why go through all this monkey business?

Comment: Because the object is not a viewController... otherwise you're right and this would be really easy ;) It's a view that's superimposed.

Comment: Using this answer I do get the correct rotation. However the delay seems to still be needed in order for my display update to correctly redraw the sizes.